# Cronjob every hour from 17 to 6

Tags: cron

I want to run a job every hour between 5 pm to 6 am.This is what I have tried

0 17-6 * * * command

But this doesn't work.

How will i set cronjob for the above?

Should two cronjobs have to be configured?

Answer (score 1):

Ranges have to be in increasing order. Instead of `17-6` you want `0-6,17-23`.